# Route-Dependent CSS Page Transitions in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and would like to implement route dependent page transitions. For example, I would like the page to slide left, slide right or fade depending on the route.

My 'Plunker' below achieves this by listening to the $routeChangeSuccess event and then applying a transition style specific CSS class to the entering and leaving view (inspired by http://phillippuleo.com/articles/scalable-approach-page-transitions-angularjs):

http://plnkr.co/edit/ee4CHfb8kZC1WxtDM9wr?p=preview

However, the call to $scope.$apply() in the event listener makes AngularJS issue an error message '$digest already in progress'. But if I don't call $scope.$apply() the CSS class of the leaving view is not updated and the animation does not work correctly.

What is going on here?

Comment: Remove `apply()` on handles the call.

Comment: If I remove apply() the CSS class of the entering view does not get updated and the transition does not work correctly.

Comment: I updated my answer. hope that helps

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I looked in your plunker. The problem is with the way you use classes to animate your views.

When the `$routeChangeSuccess` event is fired, `ngView` had already removed the class before you get the chance of changing the direction. You override it by applying the new class so quickly so it would not be noticed but then you get the digest in progress error.

#### My solution ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yrHXcYDPTxOJGG6btHJX?p=preview)):

#### I came up with a directive:

```js
app.directive('animClass',function($route){
  return {
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
      var enterClass = $route.current.animate;
      elm.addClass(enterClass);
      scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
        elm.removeClass(enterClass);
        elm.addClass($route.current.animate);
      })
    }
  }
});
```

#### Declare an `animate` option for each route:

```js
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when("/page1", {
      templateUrl: "page1.html",
      controller: "Page1Ctrl",
      animate: "slideLeft"
    }).
    when("/page2", {
      templateUrl: "page2.html",
      controller: "Page2Ctrl",
      animate: "slideRight"
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: "/page1"
    });
});
```

#### And just add it to `ngView` like so:

```html
<div ng-view ng-controller="ViewCtrl" anim-class class="view"></div>
```

#### css:

```css
.view {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 1em;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.slideLeft.ng-enter, .slideLeft.ng-leave, .slideRight.ng-enter, .slideRight.ng-leave  {
    -webkit-transition:all 1s;
    transition:all 1s;
}

.slideLeft.ng-enter {
    left:100%;
}

.slideLeft.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    left:0;
}

.slideLeft.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    left:-100%;
}

.slideRight.ng-enter {
    left:-100%;
}

.slideRight.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    left:0;
}

.slideRight.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    left:100%;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that if I don't call $scope.$apply() then the CSS class of the entering view does not get updated. So this solution does not work for me.

Comment: I really appreciate you looking into my code. Your CSS makes it work in this particular case but does not solve the real issue that one of views has CSS class 'slideLeft' and the other one 'slideRight' even though both should have the same class (both views use ng-class="animationStyle"). For example, if I add slide up/down transitions or fades it will no longer be possible to tweak the CSS to make it work.

Comment: Thanks, I really like this solution! Would you mind including the CSS classes for future reference (in case the Plunker gets deleted)?

Comment: This is stunning code. Thank you for sharing it with the community. (In other words, +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently my approach to this is to check whether angular is already within a digest cycle or not by using this snippet:

```
if (!($scope.$$phase)) $scope.$apply();
```

That's not very pretty, but unfortunately it's the only approach I've discovered so far for exactly the problem you're describing.

Comment: Thanks, the if condition evaluates to false in my case and $scope.$apply() is not called. Maybe I did not describe it well above: If I call $scope.$apply() I get an error message, if I don't call it my view does not get updated. So either way it does not work.

Comment: Umm, the condition prevents `$apply()` from being called only if you already are _applying_, so either way it will be called.
But the link of Ilan Frumer already gives quite elaborate answers to the problem.

Comment: I tried your code with my 'Plunker' and it makes the error message go away BUT then my view is not updated and the transition does not work correctly.