# Angular - Change css class on route state change based on $stateParams

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a div in the layout page:

```
<div class="{{$root.containerClass}}">...</div>
```

There are two route states:

```
.state('controllerAction', {
    url: '/:controller/:action',
    templateUrl: function($stateParams) {
         return $stateParams.controller + '/' + $stateParams.action;
    },
    controllerProvider: function($stateParams) {
         return $stateParams.controller + $stateParams.action + 'Controller';
    },
    onEnter: function($rootScope, $stateParams) {
        $rootScope.containerId = $stateParams.controller.toLowerCase() + '-index';
    }
})
.state('controller', {
    url: '/:controller',
    templateUrl: function($stateParams) {
         return $stateParams.controller + '/index';
    },
    controllerProvider: function($stateParams) {
         return $stateParams.controller + 'Controller';
    },
    onEnter: function($rootScope, $stateParams) {
        $rootScope.containerId = $stateParams.controller.toLowerCase() + '-index';
    }
});
```

I'd like the `class` to be changed when the route changes using `$stateParams`. With the code above it does changes, but only to the `containerClass` of the **previous** route.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check my other answer: [Route-Dependent CSS Page Transitions in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211460/route-dependent-css-page-transitions-in-angularjs/21211543#21211543)

I got it working with `onEnter` , plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/LEMntLYosA2gIvNzw5gv?p=preview

#### I prefer doing something like this

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/3Wof05ck3lVLqgTBDOew?p=preview

Listen to a `$stateChangeSuccess` event:

**States:**

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: '/account/index.html',
    controller: 'AccountLoginController',
    containerClass: 'account-index'
})
.state('book', {
    url: '/Book',
    templateUrl: '/book/index.html',
    controller: 'BookController',
    containerClass: 'book-index'
})
```

**Run block:**

```
app.run(function($rootScope){

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        $rootScope.containerClass = toState.containerClass;
    });

});
```

**Markup:**

```
<div ng-class="{{containerClass}}">...</div>
```

Comment: It is my bad. I tried to simplify the question so that it may help to the wider range of people. There is actually also `$stateParams` involved. Please see updated question.

Comment: nvermind. Your solution works for updated version as well. The only thing is... I was trying to apply class to the div that is also a `ui-view` container and for some reason it would not do it. I just made a wrapper div and all started working.

Comment: I recommend creating a directive on `ui-view` element , check my other answer again : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211460/route-dependent-css-page-transitions-in-angularjs/21211543#21211543

Comment: @Ilan Frumer I have it running in my app BUT... it won't take any class in ng-class="{{containerClass}}". It only takes html text e.g., "class: {{containerClass}}" that you have in your plunker, I edited that and couldn't get it to take a new class either. Please Help me!

Comment: @totallytotallyamazing It should be `ng-class="containerClass"` **without the interpolation**, check this out: http://plnkr.co/edit/AJsVNHMcSLM95F4LYZMy?p=preview

Comment: @Ilan Frumer Thanks that did it! Just a suggestion, edit your "Markup:" section on this post to reflect that. This post helped me immensely!

Answer (score 1):

You need :

- a slugify filter
- to associate $state to the $rootScope
- modify your root template to include this variable.

**First**

Associate `$state` to `$rootScope`

```
angular.module("your-app", ['ui.router'])
        .run(['$rootScope',
              '$state',
              '$stateParams',
            function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
                $rootScope.$state = $state;
                $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
            }]);
```

**Second**

Include a slugify filter. something like this: http://paulsmith.github.io/angular-slugify/

**Thirdly**

```
<body id="{{$state.current.name|slugify}}"> ... </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is allways better **use directives for DOM manipulation** and this is the case. In this example I'm using  **[ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)**

Here is my code I'm using

**Directive:**

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module( 'directives' ).directive( 'bodyClass', bodyClass );

bodyClass.$inject = [ '$rootScope'];

function bodyClass(  $rootScope  ) {
    return function( scope, elem, attr ) {

        $rootScope.$on( "$stateChangeSuccess", function( event, next, current    ) {
            var url = next.name.replace( /\./g, '-' );
            elem.attr( 'class', '' ).addClass( url );
        } );
    };
}
;
})();
```

**HTML**

```
<body body-class></body>
```

**RESULT**

So if you have URL like: **app/welcome** your body class will be :

```
<body class="app-welcome"></body>
```

Comment: this doesn't work as you will add a class each time the $state changes, the old class won't be removed

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<div class="{{$root.containerClass}}">...</div>
```

to

```
<div ng-class="containerClass">...</div>
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass
So, make use of `ng-class` directive, and when you want to access a scope variable (either local or root), just state the name, do not use `$root`