# Changing ng-view animation class dynamically with Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to toggle between two animation classes within my ng-view. This is how I have my ng-view setup in my html:

```
 <div id="animation-container" class="view-animate-container">
    <div id="ng-view" ng-view class="view-animate"></div>
  </div>
```

And here is the css for my first animation

```
.view-animate.ng-enter, .view-animate.ng-leave {
-webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.8s;
transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.8s;
display:block;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;

 }

 .view-animate.ng-enter {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
 }
 .view-animate.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
 .view-animate.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
 }
```

2nd animation:

```
.view-leave.ng-enter, .view-leave.ng-leave {
-webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.8s;
-moz-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.8s;
-o-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.8s;
transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.8s;

display:block;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;

}
 .view-leave.ng-enter {
opacity:0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
 }
 .view-leave.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
opacity:1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
 .view-leave.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
opacity:0;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}
```

All I'm trying to do is change the class from view-enter to view-leave when the back button is clicked.

```
 <a  id="back-btn" class="btn back" href="javascript:history.back()">BACK</a>
```

This Jquery code I wrote almost got the job done, but not 100%:

```
$("#back-btn").click(function(){

$("#ng-view").attr('class','view-leave');

});
```

It seemed to animate the leaving container in the right direction, but not the entering container. So I'm looking for a simple solution to what seems like a simple problem.

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211460/route-dependent-css-page-transitions-in-angularjs/21211543#21211543

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just for anyone else that might be looking for a simple solution to this question, expanding off @muenchdo answer. I set a timeout to revert to the previous animation after the transition was over.

like this:

```
$scope.animationClass = "view-enter";  
$scope.toggleAnimation = function() {
        $scope.animationClass = "view-leave";
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.animationClass = "view-enter";
      }, 350);  
}
```

This was the simplest way I could find out there, hopefully this helps someone out there that is looking for a simple solution to what seems like simple functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need `jQuery` for this, you can use Angular's `ng-class` attribute. Add an `ng-click` to your back button which calls a function inside your controller. Something like this:

In your HTML:

```
<div id="animation-container" class="view-animate-container">
    <div id="ng-view" ng-view class="view-animate" ng-class="animationClass"></div>
</div>

<a class="btn back" href="javascript:history.back()" ng-click="toggleAnimation()">BACK</a>
```

In your Controller:

```
$scope.animationClass = "view-enter";

$scope.toggleAnimation = function() {
    if ($scope.animationClass === "view-enter") {
        $scope.animationClass = "view-leave";
    } else if ($scope.animationClass === "view-leave") {
        $scope.animationClass = "view-enter";
    }
};
```

Comment: This helped alot, thanks @muenchdo, the one problem I had with this though is it seems to keep the view-leave class until I click the back button again. Is there a simple way of running the toggle animation once then toggling back to the original without having to click back again?

Comment: @JoeKomputer Yes, you're right, it does not reset the class. The simplest way would probably to also call the toggle function before you enter the view in which you have your back button. If that is possible in your situation, it might make sense to split the toggle function into two separate functions (e.g. `activateEnter` and `activateLeave`) just to make sure you don't run into inconsistencies. If that doesn't work for you, I guess you will have to look into [JavaScript defined animations](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found a different way with the new `$routeChangeStart` event.
This solution saves history to check if the next page is actually the previous page.

Place this in your controlller:

```
$scope.backward = false;
$scope.history = [];

$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current) {
  var previous = $scope.history[$scope.history.length - 2];
  if (previous && current.originalPath === previous.originalPath) {
    $scope.backward = true;
    $scope.history.pop();
  } else {
    $scope.backward = false;
    $scope.history.push(current);
  }
});
```

Then use a container around your `ng-view` with an `ng-class` reacting to the `$scope.backward`.

```
<div ng-class="{'backward': backward}">
    <ng-view class="view-animate">
</div>
```

And have two CSS animations. The forward on `.view-animate` or whatever class you use for your `ng-view`. And the backward on `.backward .view-animate`.